# Tags SQL em consulta

Tags: java, mysql, sql, oracle

Estou iniciando meus estudos em SQL e não sei qual significado desta estrutura abaixo. Gostaria de saber o que são essas tags.

Estou usando em Java. Tenho um arquivo `mapper.xml` para criar consultas no Hibernate.

```
 < SELECT
       <choose>
           <when test="filtro.veiculo.name() == 'VAGAO'">
                tipoVagaoTrad.Xfpdstsv AS TIPO_VAGAO,
                serieVagao.Xflcdsvg AS SERIE,
                vagao.xfrcdvag AS VAGAO,
                frotaVagao.Xf5cdflo AS FROTA,
                frotaVagao.Xf5tpflo AS TIPO_FROTA_VAGAO,
                frotaVagaoTrad.Xm9dscfl AS DESCRICAO_FROTA,
                vagao.xfrindrg AS REGIME,
           </when>
           <otherwise>
               modeloLocomotiva.X, 
               locomotiva.xf0cdloc || '-' || empProp.XN4CDEMP AS LOCOMOTIVA,
               frotaLocomotiva.Xf2cdflo AS FROTA,
               frotaLocomotiva.Xf2tpflo AS TIPO_FROTA_LOCOMOTIVA,
               frotaLocomotivaTrad.Xm8dscfl AS DESCRICAO_FROTA,
               locomotiva.xf0indrg AS REGIME,
               folhaEspLocomotiva.Xf3poliq AS HP_LOCOMOTIVA,
           </otherwise> 
       </choose>
```

Comment: De onde você tirou essas tags? Que ferramenta utiliza isso? Nunca vi SQL sendo escrita com tags.

Comment: Tem que ter mais detalhes nessa pergunta. Vamos adivinhar de onde esse xml apareceu?

Comment: Agora que você editou, ficou bem melhor. Uma pena que a sua pergunta acabou levando tanto voto negativo por estar tão ruim inicialmente. De qualquer forma, já dei o voto de reabertura (só falta mais um) e já tenho uma resposta que postarei quando ela for reaberta. Adianto que isso daí é JSTL, uma tecnologia que é usada em JSP.

Comment: Já tenho a resposta pronta, só estou esperando a reabertura para postar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso daí é JSTL, que é uma tecnologia da JSP.

O **JSP** (*Java Server Pages*) é a tecnologia padrão do Java para se produzir páginas HTML e websites dinâmicos.
Os JSPs são compilados para servlets por um compilador especial existente no container de aplicação.
Os servlets são classes Java responsáveis por processar requisições HTTP e produzir respostas HTTP.

Uma página produzida por um JSP inclui partes estáticas e partes dinâmicas.
Dá para se dizer que o JSP é um poderoso framework de processamento de templates. Ou seja, ele contrói strings que tenham sido parcialmente modeladas a serem preenchidas com partes dinâmicas. Mais ou menos como um `String.format` ou `String.printf`, porém com muito mais versatilidade e flexibilidade e projetado para processar lógica complexa no processo de montagem da `String` resultante.

No JSP, há duas formas de se definir as partes dinâmicas, uma é por meio de scriptlets (considerados obsoletos) e a outra é por meio de taglibs, que são bibliotecas de tags customizadas. Cada uma dessas tags customizadas corresponde a uma parte de geração de texto dinâmica no JSP, sendo renderizada por meio de lógica complexa implementada por meio de classes Java.

A **JSTL** (*JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library*) é a biblioteca padrão do JSP que contém várias dessas tags já customizadas. Dentre essas tags temos:

- `<c:if>` - Processa o conteúdo da tag se uma determinada condição for verdadeira. Caso contrário, pula o corpo da tag. Como o nome sugere, é o equivalente ao `if` na JSP.
- `<c:out>` - Avalia uma expressão em tempo de execução e concatena o seu resultado no texto sendo gerado dinamicamente.
- `<c:forEach>` - Repete várias vezes o conteúdo da tag, ao iterar uma coleção de elementos. Como o nome sugere, isso é o equivalente no JSP ao *enhanced-for* do Java.
- `<c:choose>` - Contém várias tags `<c:when>` e opcionalmente uma tag `<c:otherwise>`. Isso é o equivalente ao Java de uma sequência de `if`s e `else if`s e `else`.
- `<c:when>` - Semelhante a um `if` ou `else if` que estiver dentro de um `<c:choose>` - Processa o conteúdo da tag se uma expressão for verdadeira, tal como o `if`. A diferença do `<c:when>` e do `<c:if>` é que apenas o primeiro `<c:when>` de dentro do `<c:choose>` que tiver a expressão verdadeira vai ter o seu corpo processado, em detrimento dos demais.
- `<c:otherwise>` - Equivalente a um `else` - Processa o corpo se nenhum `<c:when>` antecedente dentro do `<c:choose>` tiver a condição verdadeira.

Há também várias outras tags na JSTL, mas essas acima são as principais e as mais usadas.

Para fazer o processamento da JSTL, o JSP utiliza a EL (*Expression Language*) que é uma sublinguagem simples que avalia expressões em tempo de execução. A EL é capaz de chamar métodos, manipular objetos do tipo Java Beans, fazer cálculos aritméticos, entre outras coisas.

Normalmente JSP e JSTL são utilizados para gerar HTML ou XML de forma dinâmica, mas nada impede de utilizá-lo para outras coisas, tal como gerar SQL, e é isso que ocorre no seu caso.

Acredito que o seu código seja antecedido por algo assim:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Isso daí é o que declara que a JSTL está sendo importada no seu JSP. Ele também declara que a JSTL vai ser importada usando-se o prefixo `c`.

No seu código, acredito que ele contém `<c:choose>`, `<c:when>` e `<c:otherwise>` ao invés de apenas `<choose>`, `<when>` e `<otherwise>`. Esse prefixo `c` é importante, e é o prefixo que foi definido lá no `<%@ taglib`. Vamos então ver esse código:

```xml
SELECT
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="filtro.veiculo.name() == 'VAGAO'">
        tipoVagaoTrad.Xfpdstsv AS TIPO_VAGAO,
        serieVagao.Xflcdsvg AS SERIE,
        vagao.xfrcdvag AS VAGAO,
        frotaVagao.Xf5cdflo AS FROTA,
        frotaVagao.Xf5tpflo AS TIPO_FROTA_VAGAO,
        frotaVagaoTrad.Xm9dscfl AS DESCRICAO_FROTA,
        vagao.xfrindrg AS REGIME,
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        modeloLocomotiva.X, 
        locomotiva.xf0cdloc || '-' || empProp.XN4CDEMP AS LOCOMOTIVA,
        frotaLocomotiva.Xf2cdflo AS FROTA,
        frotaLocomotiva.Xf2tpflo AS TIPO_FROTA_LOCOMOTIVA,
        frotaLocomotivaTrad.Xm8dscfl AS DESCRICAO_FROTA,
        locomotiva.xf0indrg AS REGIME,
        folhaEspLocomotiva.Xf3poliq AS HP_LOCOMOTIVA,
    </c:otherwise> 
</c:choose>
```

Esse `"filtro.veiculo.name() == 'VAGAO'"` é uma expressão de EL que pega o objeto `filtro`, acessa o método `getVeiculo()` e então acessa o método `name()` e compara o resultado com a `String` `"VAGAO"`, obtendo um `boolean` como resultado, sendo esse `boolean` o resultado da expressão.
Na EL, não há problema em comparar `String`s usando EL, pois ele sempre usa o `equals` por baixo dos panos.

Se o resultado da EL for verdadeiro, a condição do `<c:when>` vai ser verdadeira e o bloco entre o `<c:when>` e o `</c:when>` vai ser colocado no texto de saída.

Se o resultado da EL for falso (e consequentemente a condição do `<c:when>`), o `<c:choose>` segue no bloco seguinte e entra no `<c:otherwise>`, e portanto o conteúdo entre o `<c:otherwise>` e o `</c:otherwise>` vai ser colocado no texto de saída.

Assim sendo, o que esse código faz é o seguinte:

- Se o nome do veículo do filtro for "`VAGAO`", então é gerada a seguinte SQL:

  ```sql
  SELECT
          tipoVagaoTrad.Xfpdstsv AS TIPO_VAGAO,
          serieVagao.Xflcdsvg AS SERIE,
          vagao.xfrcdvag AS VAGAO,
          frotaVagao.Xf5cdflo AS FROTA,
          frotaVagao.Xf5tpflo AS TIPO_FROTA_VAGAO,
          frotaVagaoTrad.Xm9dscfl AS DESCRICAO_FROTA,
          vagao.xfrindrg AS REGIME,
  ```
- Caso contrário, gera a seguinte SQL:

  ```sql
  SELECT
          modeloLocomotiva.X, 
          locomotiva.xf0cdloc || '-' || empProp.XN4CDEMP AS LOCOMOTIVA,
          frotaLocomotiva.Xf2cdflo AS FROTA,
          frotaLocomotiva.Xf2tpflo AS TIPO_FROTA_LOCOMOTIVA,
          frotaLocomotivaTrad.Xm8dscfl AS DESCRICAO_FROTA,
          locomotiva.xf0indrg AS REGIME,
          folhaEspLocomotiva.Xf3poliq AS HP_LOCOMOTIVA,
  ```

Mais informações sobre a JSTL podem ser encontradas em:

- Na [apostila Java para desenvolvimento web da Caelum (capítulo 7)](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/usando-taglibs/).
- No livro [Use a Cabeça - Servlets & JSP, de Bryan Basham, Kathy Sierra e Bert Bates](http://www.saraiva.com.br/use-a-cabeca-servlets-e-jsp-2624100.html) - embora esse livro já esteja um tanto ultrapassado.

Ah, e tudo isso não tem nada a ver com o Hibernate e nem com o arquivo `mapper.xml`.

---

**NOTA**: Na pergunta como ela estava originalmente, não identifiquei que isso seria JSTL (embora tenha percebido a semelhança) por causa das tags `<select>` e `<where>` que estavam na pergunta original, uma vez que essas tags não são JSTL, estava faltando o atributo `test` na tag `when` e as tags estavam sem o prefixo `c:`.